# Replace space in string only if followed by certain characters

Tags: regex

Im trying to replace all spaces in a string only if they are followed by a certain number os characters. My example:

```
DKR N872 DEMIR UN872 DENOX UZ319 MOPIL
DKR DEMIR DENOX MOPIL TRS N866 ELTOK
```

Current output:

```
DKR N872 DEMIR UN872 DENOX UZ319 MOPIL
DKR DCT DEMIR DENOX DCT MOPIL TRS N866 ELTOK
```

What i want is:

```
DKR N872 DEMIR UN872 DENOX UZ319 MOPIL
DKR DCT DEMIR DCT DENOX DCT MOPIL DCT TRS N866 ELTOK
```

My regex:

```
(?<fix1>[A-Z]{3,5}) (?<fix2>[A-Z]{3,5})

Replacement:
$1 DCT $2
```

As you can se, in my current output it skips the parts that's hase already been "involved" in the last replace. Like between DEMIR & DENOX.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're almost there `(?<fix1>[A-Z]{3,5}) (?<fix2>(?=[A-Z]{3,5}))` Replace with `$1 DCT $2`
note the look ahead operator `?=`